# how to validate data retrieved from db using jmeter?

Tags: automated-tests, jmeter, functional-testing

I want to retrieve the data from a db using jmeter and take the results, compare with values which i sent in request. Can anyone suggest me few ideas on how to accomplish this using jmeter only? i'm able to store the message in db and retrieve the same data( saved in the form of file). but i am not able to compare further.

Thanks,
Bharath

Answer (score 0):

To validate the response, you'll want to use [ASSERTION SAMPLERS](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions), of which there are several you may find useful for what you're doing.